# How to get the JSON representation of an object with an array variable

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this class with three variables, one of them being an array. I have written a method that I'll use inside json_encode().

```
public function getJSONString(){
     return [
         'id' => $this->id,
         'name' => $this->name,
         'books' => $this->books
     ];
}
```

books is an array of Book objects. Each Book object also has the same exact method but then with its own variables.

```
public function getJSONString(){
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title
    ];
}
```

When I call print(json_encode($author->getJSONString())) I recieve this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"name1","books":[{},{}]}
```

Any idea why books remains empty? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably  `$this->books` is empty. Check if it's empty `var_dump($this->books)` and check the code that sets it's value may be it is executing after you called `getJSONString()`

Comment: Books are empty because they're empty initially. `print_r()` your variable and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `Book`s' `getJSONString()` methods as well. This will make the the `books` property equal to an array of JSON-encode-able objects.

In the author's `getJSONString()` method:

```
public function getJSONString(){
     return [
         'id' => $this->id,
         'name' => $this->name,
         'books' => array_map(function($book) { return $book->getJSONString(); }, $this->books)
     ];
}
```

I am not fluent in PHP, but you can get the idea from this. It maps a function to get the `getJSONString()` over the `books` array.

Comment: I get the idea of calling getJSONString of every book but I think in this example it's calling the wrong getJSONString method. See the class Book has it's own implementation of the method, and right now I think it keeps calling the getJSONString in the same class where $books is declared?

Comment: @Notorious Oops, I made a silly mistake in my first code. I changed it so that it uses `$book->getJSONString()`. Tell me if it works now.

Comment: Works fine now. Appreciate the help alot!

Comment: @Notorious Glad I helped!

Comment: This is not a good way to do it. Using `JsonSerializer` is the cleaner way to go.  See my answer.

Comment: I understand JsonSerializer is usually the way to go but in this example I was told to use my own interface and method to get a JSON representation of an object. Thanks anyway @abeyaz

Comment: Why does he need to use the Books' getJSONString() methods as well ? `json_encode` [can encode the books as well if it is not empty](https://eval.in/992309)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [JsonSerializable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

```
class Book implements JsonSerializable 
{
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
           'id' => $this->id,
           'title' => $this->title
        ];
    }
}
```

When you call `json_encode` for an object of this class or anything contains that, php will call your `jsonSerialize` method. Similar to what you are trying to do, but this is the language specific and right way to do it. Other languages like C# has similar interfaces too.